# How to get Mid point of <g> tag in svg using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am working in SVG  tags using javascript. I tried to get group tag `<g>` midpoint in svg. Is it possible to get mid point value of group tag using javascript? 
Here's my demo group tag `<g>`

```
<g id="object_7" transform="translate(573,703) scale(0.5,0.51)" style="pointer-events:inherit">

<path d="m-40,-19l3,-3l74,0l3,3l0,37l-3,3l-74,0l-3,-3l0,-37z" id="uid127" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#1e1d19" stroke="#000000"/>

   <path d="m-9,21l4,2l10,0l4,-2" id="uid129" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>

   <path d="m-40,-19l3,-3l74,0l3,3l-77,40l-3,-3l0,-37z" id="uid131" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.12" fill="#000000"/>

</g>
```

Here I need to get midpoint point of group tag. I used to get mouse co-ordinates for getting center of x and y position in group tag, but I did not achieve it. Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the bounding box of the `<g>` element by getting a reference to it and calling the function `getBBox()`.

```
var  bbox = document.getElementById("object_7").getBBox();
```

Note however that this is the union of all the bounding boxes of the group's children.  If the group has a transform, it is not reflected in the bbox value.  If you are adding elements to the group, this is probably the one you want.

If you want the bounds of the object in screen space, then you can get the group element's transform and apply it to the centre point you have calculated.

```
var  ctm = document.getElementById("object_7").getCTM()

// Calculate the centre of the group
var cx = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
var cy = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;

// Transform cx,cy by the group's transform
var pt = document.getElementById("mysvg").createSVGPoint();
pt.x = cx;
pt.y = cy;
pt = pt.matrixTransform(ctm);

// centre point in screen coordinates is in pt.x and pt.y
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/9oz6ozp4/)

Comment: Its results only screen center value,but i need to get object mid point value? how to get through it? can pls guide me..

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean by "object mid point value"? You don't want the "centre of object"?

Comment: Yes i want center of group object.But, in your code results only working area screen center.i want to drag svg object and place in working area. i need to get individual svg object center..

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "working area screen center".  If you want the centre of any element in local coordinates, call `getBBox()` on it and use the cx,cy calculation above.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get absolute middle point/position of `g` tag in screen:

```
let el = document.getElementById("object_7")
let midX = (el.getBoundingClientRect().left + el.getBoundingClientRect().right) / 2
let midY = (el.getBoundingClientRect().top + el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom) / 2
```

It also works for other svg elements.