# find coordinates of the middle of a square svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Let's say I have a svg square

```
<svg>
    <rect x="4" y="4" width="80" height="60" id="block_green"/>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to find the exact center, in this case (44, 34), in a flexible way so that even if I wrote:

```
<svg>
    <rect x="4" y="4" width="80" height="60" transform="rotate(15, 44, 34) id="block_green"/>
</svg>
```

This question is different to [How to get Mid point of <g> tag in svg using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867641/how-to-get-mid-point-of-g-tag-in-svg-using-javascript) in that
I want to know the center of the square **even after** css3 animations, transformation. And I want it to be stored like this:

```
ss.cx = "x center coordinates";
ss.cy = "y center coordinates";
```

Comment: Is the transform always a rotation about the centre point?

Comment: Your current transform won't affect the position of the rectangle's centre point. Other transforms might. I am trying to determine whether we have to account for the latter type of transforms.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yes, in fact, I will be using css in order to move the square around, but I want to keep track of where the center is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can find center of this by calculating like :

```
centerX = (rectX + rectWidth)/2
centerY = (rectY + rectHeight)/2
```

But this wont work after applying transform because if you notice,co-ordinates don't really change when you apply transform.

You may need help of trigonometry or geometry to find new transformed co-ordinates.