# finding coordinates of center of rectangle svg

Tags: javascript, svg

This is the troublesome code [find coordinates of the middle of a square svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316720/find-coordinates-of-the-middle-of-a-square-svg)

The code snippet below doesn't work here. You might want to use another editor or check the lin above for easy access.

```js
$(function() {
 var ss = {
  "y": 40,
  "x": 4,
  "n": 3, // Speed
  "xD": 0,
  "yD": 0,
  "rotation": 0,
  /*"cx":, This is where I want my coords to change
  "cy":,*/
 };
 var move;
 var bbox = document.getElementById("block_green").getBBox();
 var ctm = document.getElementById("block_green").getCTM()
 var cx = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
 var cy = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
 var pt = document.getElementById("svg").createSVGPoint();
 pt.x = cx;
 pt.y = cy;
 pt = pt.matrixTransform(ctm);
 setInterval(move, .01);
 setInterval(alert(pt.x + ", " pt.y), 20000);

 function move() {
  ss.x = ss.x + (ss.xD * ss.n);
  ss.y = ss.y + (ss.yD * ss.n);
  $("#block_green").attr({
      y: ss.y,
   x: ss.x
    }).css({
   "-webkit-transform" : "rotate("+ ss.rotation +"deg)",
   "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + ss.rotation + "deg)",
   "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + ss.rotation + "deg)",
   "transform": "rotate(" + ss.rotation + "deg)"
  });
 }
 

 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
   ss.rotation = e.which == 37 ? ss.rotation -2 : ss.rotation;
   ss.rotation = e.which == 39 ? ss.rotation +2 : ss.rotation
  ss.yD = e.which == 38 ? -1 : ss.yD;
  ss.yD = e.which == 40 ? 1 : ss.yD;
  ss.xD = e.which == 69 ? 1 : ss.xD;
  ss.xD = e.which == 81 ? -1 : ss.xD;
   e.preventDefault();
 }).keyup(function(e) {
  ss.yD = e.which == 38 ? 0 : ss.yD;
  ss.yD = e.which == 40 ? 0 : ss.yD;
  ss.xD = e.which == 69 ? 0 : ss.xD;
  ss.xD = e.which == 81 ? 0 : ss.xD;
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 z-index: 1;
}

#block_green {
 fill: black;
 stroke: #00ff00;
 stroke-width: .5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg">
 <rect x="4" y="4" width="80" height="60" id="block_green"/>
</svg>
```

This code should alert every 20 seconds, the coordinates of the square. In order to get the coordinates of the center of the square, I've tryied this question:
[How to get Mid point of <g> tag in svg using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867641/how-to-get-mid-point-of-g-tag-in-svg-using-javascript)
If you are using codepen, you'll find the proble in lines `9-16` & `18`.

Comment: The answer to the linked question does that. Please explain exactly why that answer does not solve your problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson When I used that same code to find the coordinates of one the boxes I had, It didn't not seem to work, which made me think that the animations and css3 transformations may have to do something with it

Comment: You need to add such a testcase to the question then.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you, I'll make sure to add it

Comment: @RobertLongson done, you can now see exactlt what I'm trying to acomplish! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a syntax error in your code which will prevent its execution:

```
setInterval(alert(pt.x + ", " pt.y), 20000);
```

needs to be

```
setInterval(alert(pt.x + ", " + pt.y), 20000);
```

But that's not the major point here. The way you are trying to set up your interval will not work as expected. It will not repeatedly call `alert()` but instead evaluate the expression `alert(pt.x + ", " + pt.y)` **once** when you call `setInterval()`. For this reason you will see one initial alert popup printing the starting values for `pt`. The expression will eventually evaluate to `undefined` which will be taken as the first argument to `setInterval()`, i.e. the function to call repeatedly is referred to as `undefined`, which obviously is not what you intended in the first place.

You need to wrap the calculations of the rect's center in a function if you want to have it alert the updated values on repeated calls. You are then able to pass the reference to a function, not to `undefined` to `setInterval()`. Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8z5yd1n/3/) for the way it might work for you:

```
function getCenter() {
    var bbox = document.getElementById("block_green").getBBox();
    var ctm = document.getElementById("block_green").getCTM()
    var cx = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
    var cy = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
    var pt = document.getElementById("svg").createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = cx;
    pt.y = cy;
    return pt.matrixTransform(ctm);
}        

setInterval(function() {
    var pt = getCenter();
    alert(pt.x + ", " + pt.y);
}, 20000);
```

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle and it alerts "[object SVGPoint]" instead of the actual point like this: `(x, y)`

Comment: I edited my answer and updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8z5yd1n/3/) to better fit your question.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that by applying the transformation of the element to its center. This way is a general approach to obtain absolute coordinates from a local space. The idea is: Compute the center of the rectangle in local coordinates, by using the attribute values directly. Afterwards one applies the transformation of the svg element to that point.

```
var svg = document.getElementById('root'),
    rect = document.getElementById('block_green'),
    x = rect.x.baseVal.value,
    y = rect.x.baseVal.value,
    w = rect.width.baseVal.value,
    h = rect.height.baseVal.value,
    c = svg.createSVGPoint(),
    mtr = rect.getTransformToElement(svg);

 c.x = x + w/2;
 c.y = y + h/2;

 c = c.matrixTransform(mtr);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wnj0vwyd/1/)

Comment: sorry, just updated to a more compleate and detailed description of what I needed on request

Comment: Did not say that it was you! But thanks for supporting my efffort!!

Comment: Shouldn't this:
"x = rect.x.baseVal.value, y = rect.x.baseVal.value,"
be
"x = rect.x.baseVal.value,  y = rect.y.baseVal.value,"

y = rect.y ... in case you missed it. So, code does not work.